# Best way to draw paths on web page

Tags: html, silverlight, flash, animation

I have vector map of India and I need to draw the travelled path in an "Indiana Jones-esque" style, if you know what I mean.

The lines need extend from point to point.

At the moment, Im using Rapheal.js to draw it but it is proving laborious to find all of the pixel positions on photoshop and then write them in to the raphael drawing method.

I could use silverlight, but a lot of people do not have it installed and it doesnt seem widespread enough.

I could use flash, but then it wouldnt be compatible with iPhone.

What would be the best way to draw these lines on a web page?

Comment: I would stick with JavaScript in this case, maybe look into HTML5 Canvas as well. Flash would make it easier but manually finding the points is likely what you'll have to end up doing.

Comment: Is this path going to be dynamically generated, or can it work as an image?

Comment: @iND It could work as a static image. Theres only going to be a few maps and the path will always be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Adobe Illustrator or Flash to produce an image file, then put that on your website.

For Illustrator, put the map on the background layer, and in the foreground layer(s), put the points for your map and the lines that connect them.  Then export as a PNG or JPG, and put it on your website as an image.

For Flash, use the timeline and follow the same process, making separate layers for your points and lines.  Then use ***File -> Export -> Export Image . . .*** and select the PNG or JPG file type, then put it on your website as an image.

For a free vector image program (the program you would use to draw and style the path), try using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).